# control system satellite - bdot

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I am in charge with developing a control system for a satellite. But there are a few things, about the mathematics, which are not so clear:

- $\dot{B}_{x}$ rate of change of $B_x$ with respect to time $t$;
- $B_x = B_o\cos (wzt)$ <---OK
- $\dot{B}_x = -B_o wz \sin(wzt)$ <--- how?

Here you have the formula in its context
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QciLJ.jpg

Comment: The second line is the derivative of the first with respect to $t$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Omg yes, soo stupid of me. But why do you need a derivative in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bx = Bo. cos (wzt) <---OK"

Through derivation you get the next one. Bdotx is supposed to mean derived Bx.

The dipole uses the derivative, that is why it's needed. Just like derivative of acceleration is speed.

Comment: when I apply the product rule I get a completely different result. Could you please briefely explain your steps?

Comment: you mean vector product? M=-kBdotx, k is a scalar not a vector, so you multiply like a scalar. Is this what you asked?